# How does trace32 debugger pro work? How can I generate and import an .elf file?

Tags: powerpc, trace32, lauterbach

I have a Lauterbach debugger pro, but do not know the work flow of the device or its software at all. I find the tutorials out on the internet from Lauterbach to be very vague and dependent on having already preinstalled tutorials. Can someone give me a drawing on how things (debugger, target, connected pc) interact with each other? I would like to know if the the target is already pre programmed, do i need to also have that program on the connected PC? if so, what/how should i do with that program to be able to live debug the target. can someone give a real life workflow in steps, because i find the tutorials hard to follow. treat it as if you're starting a debug session from nothing. all you have is a preprogrammed mpc8270 chip embedded system.

I tried following the tutorials and i did the demo sieve but I fail to see how that relates to a real situation. How do i get an .elf file? how do i view the code on the already programmed system. I have a copy of the code on the system, how do i properly import everything or load everything so that I can see the source code?